# JavaScript: get all possible values of a field in a two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, json

From API I get such a json:

```
{
    "purposes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "for-calls"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "code": "task-management"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "code": "messenger"
        }
    ],
    "availabilities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "free"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "code": "free-basic-plan"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "code": "trial-version"
        }
    ],
    "ecosystems": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "browse-widget"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "code": "web-app"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "code": "installation-on-your-server"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I iterate over this json to get a new array containing the field values 'code' from each element. As a result, there should be `/catalog/filter/value_of_code` in each element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const obj = {
  "purposes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "for-calls"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "task-management"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "messenger"
    }
  ],
  "availabilities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "free"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "free-basic-plan"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "trial-version"
    }
  ],
  "ecosystems": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "browse-widget"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "web-app"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "installation-on-your-server"
    }
  ]
}

const arr = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, e) => [...acc, ...e.map(o => `/catalog/filter/${o.code}`)] ,[]);

console.log( arr );
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are receiving this JSON object in serverResp object.
Now lets check if any catalogs are present in the object.

```
if(Object.keys(serverResp).length)
```

Next we shall iterate over the catalogs

```
Object.keys(serverResp).forEach((cat) => )
```

Each cat represents a catalog. Next we shall fetch array against each key inside our forloop

```
const catItems = serverResp[cat];
```

catItems will contain all the items of a particular catalog. Now lets iterate over each catItems to get the "code" value

```
catItems.forEach(item => console.log(item.code));
```

Final piece of code will look like below-

```
const outputArray = [];
if(Object.keys(serverResp).length) {
    Object.keys(serverResp).forEach((cat)=> {
    const catItems = serverResp[cat];
    catItems.forEach(item => 
    outputArray.push(`/catalog/filter${item.code}`));
  });
 }

 console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, can you clarify how best to insert route before the code field, something like this `/catalog/filter/purposes/values_of_code`,`/catalog/filter/availabilities/values_of_code` in one array

Comment: var outputArray = [];
if(Object.keys(serverResp).length) {
    Object.keys(serverResp).forEach((cat)=> {
    const catItems = serverResp[cat];
    catItems.forEach(item => 
    outputArray.push(`/catalog/filter/${cat}/${item.code}`));
  });
 }

 console.log(outputArray);

The above code will solve that problem. We have the value of catalog (purposes/availabilities) in cat variable